# Visual Studio 2013 does not build on f5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build

After upgrading to VS2013, hitting F5 to debug doesn't seem to build start up project and dependencies.  I've seen a couple other similar questions, but they said 'mysteriously started working' again or was on VS2010.

I have 'Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run' CHECKED.  I've seen some suggestions about unchecking this, but wondering if that is needed.  I commonly have all dependent projects in solution where only the startup and 0..N project references if I need to debug into a dependent project.  When I'm not debugging, the projects are there just for reference if I need to peek at code and I'd rather not build those on every debug session.

Any ideas on how to get VS to build on F5 AND have 'build startup and dependencies' enabled?

Comment: When you installed VS 2013, what setup scheme did you choose? I know if you choose Visual Basic F5 doesn't do the debug build

Comment: @Taegost I chose C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set your Function keys.

Go to Tools/Options,
Then Environment/Keyboard,
In 'Show commands containing', enter 'start.debug',
In 'Press shortcut keys', press F5.
Click on 'Assign' and you should be all set.

Comment: Project 'debugs'...it just doesn't build before running.  Unchecking 'build startup and deps' made it work, but I want it to indeed only build startup/deps.